# Facing this error "Error: transaction has been reverted by the evm, fail to send transaction"

Tags: solidity, web3js, revert

This is my web console error:

```
web3.min.js:22  Uncaught (in promise) Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "blockHash": "0x8fa9e80f29536d9c7797966ab687f2b537c0abf827d0c9b47734eeebcbcc60e4",
  "blockNumber": 840,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 22602,
  "effectiveGasPrice": 1000000000,
  "from": "0x98467671278cdf056d87cc65121bc2c5da80bfb5",
  "gasUsed": 22602,
  "logs": [],
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "to": "0x1d840e86a4e0e83d4cb0b39ff0d2ed33f2cc3aea",
  "transactionHash": "0x6709ff79732fc6348d214c0aeb708bd1d7664c07d8e001010f1d23124d64cc21",
  "transactionIndex": 0,
  "type": "0x0"
}
```

This is my code:

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:12345"));
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(data, '0x1D840E86A4E0e83d4Cb0b39Ff0D2eD33F2cC3aEa');
const account1 = '0x98467671278cdf056d87cc65121bc2c5da80bfb5'
console.log(this.number,this.helplist.createDate,this.helplist.donationDemand+this.helplist.projectOrganizer)
let txo = {
    from: account1,
    gasLimit:web3.utils.toHex(3000000),
    to: "0x1D840E86A4E0e83d4Cb0b39Ff0D2eD33F2cC3aEa",
    value:'0x00',
    data: contract.methods.declaring(this.number,this.helplist.createDate,this.helplist.donationDemand+this.helplist.projectOrganizer).encodeABI()
}
web3.eth.sendTransaction(txo, (err, txHash) => {
    console.log(err+'   '+txHash)
})
```

This is my contract:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract  Mappings {
    struct Employee {
        string time;
        bytes32 hash;
    }
    mapping (uint32 => Employee) bytesMapping;
    
    function getinfo(uint32 id) view public  returns(Employee memory) {
        return bytesMapping[id];
    }

    function declaring(uint32 id,string memory time,string memory information) public {
        bytes32 hash=sha256(bytes(information));
        bytesMapping[id] = Employee(time, hash);
    }
}
```

One year ago I was able to use this contract like this successfully, but now its throwing error.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Can you attach the screenshot of the output shown by this log `console.log(this.number,this.helplist.createDate,this.helplist.donationDemand+this.helplist.projectOrganizer)`?